# Showing error message on same page with a Session in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I have this situation where I am required to show where if user does not enter right password, the program will place an appropriate message in a session & will Dispatch back to the login jsp page and display the message.

I checked this one as well, [Redirect to the same page but with a message in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450944/redirect-to-the-same-page-but-with-a-message-in-it)

But when I try implement the answer, the eclipse gives me a red line over the code.

Here is my code,

```
String message = "Wrong Password!";

HttpSession session = session.setAttribute("message", message);
```

The error shown is **Type Mismatch: Cannot Convert to from void to HttpSession**

Any ideas where I am wrong or how can I do this?

Comment: _the eclipse gives me a red line over the code_ then there is some error. You need to tell us what error it shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
session.setAttribute("message", message);
```

this return type is void, hence your pionting to `HttpSessoin` Object, so it is giving showing complier error.

**Use this**

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("message", message);
```

Comment: Bad design! This kind of error should be in request scope, not in session scope.

Answer (score 1):

`session.setAttribute()` returns "`void`" and not "`HttpSession`".

You need to get the `session` from the `request` and then use `setAttribute()` on the `session` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simply the `setAttribute()` method wont return a session object.

Answer (score 0):

> HttpSession session = session.setAttribute("message", message);

Above line is wrong. you need to do just a...

```
session.setAttribute("message", message);
```

That's it. 
And on jsp page while getting session value.

```
out.println(session.getAttribute("message"));
```

or

```
<%=session.getAttribute("message")%>
```