# Not able to show the message on the same page using sessions?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

This follows from the following question of mine, [Showing error message on same page with a Session in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954099/showing-error-message-on-same-page-with-a-session-in-jsp)

I am not able to show the message on the same, it just goes back to the same page but with no message,

Here is my code,

```
if (btn.equals("Sign Up")) {
        if (pass.equals(confirmPass) && length > 6) {

        String message = "You are Validated!";

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("message", message);           
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("signUp.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
        out.println(session.getAttribute("message"));

    }
```

What could possibly be wrong in my code?

Here is my jsp,

```
<div align="center">
        <form action="Validate" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter Email</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtEmail"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select Password</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtPassword"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Confirm Password</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtConfirm"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post your jsp code for printing the message

Comment: How is your JSP page displaying the message?

Comment: where are you trying to show the error message? there is no code snippet for printing message in your jsp.

Answer (score 0):

On your JSP page, use this:

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.message}" />
```

Comment: You don't have to use the c:out tag. Just do ${sessionScope.message}. The c:out tag is to escape XML for security.

Comment: Okay, I am little clueless about this, I just have to simply paste this? o.O

Comment: Put that code on wherever you want the message to appear on your JSP page.

Comment: It indeed shows the message, but what if I want to show it after validating the conditions and clicking the sign up button?

Answer (score 0):

since you don't like to have jstl tag in your JSP, let's go back to old school solution : inline java in jsp

```
<%
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("message","message");
    if(session != null && session.getAttribute("message") != null){
        %><h1><%= session.getAttribute("message")%></h1><%
    }
%>
```

with a null/empty check, the error message will be displayed only when it is populated after validation.

Comment: For some reason, it is printing but not after I click the Sign Up button.

Comment: that means the **message** attribute is already in user session. the easiest way to fix it is to remove the session attribute from session whenever validation is passed. session.removeAttribute("message");

Comment: Are not we getting confused here? :P I just want to show the message after the user has finished clicking but not before o.O

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not really clear about **jsp/servlet** and **httpsession**. The message will not be displayed before sign up as long as the session attribute was not populated. Since you are saving message in HttpSession, you need to make sure to remove attribute when validation passed. If you don't remove it, the message will always be displayed after user first time sign up failed.

If you feel confused, I reckon you can ignore **session** and use **request** instead. In this case, you set attribute to request object like this

```
request.setAttribute("message", "error message");
```

And in jsp, change from **session.getAttribute()** to **request.getAttribute()**, and then there is no way that the message can be displayed before user sign up.